# firestore index counter total size

Tags: jquery, firebase

I have multiple information and trying to fetching from firestore in div assigning id (i.e slide-1). 
How can I create index of each div like slide-1, slide-2.....

Also on load all the information show like attached image.
I have to trigger some action to work properly (may be resize window manual)

[image]

**JQuery**

```
docRef
    .orderBy("order")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      totalRecords = querySnapshot.size;
      console.log(totalRecords);
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        // console.log(data.title);

        const slide =
          `
        <div id="slide-`+ 1 +`" class="slide fullbleed prt"><div
            class="bg-image"
            style="background-image: url(`+ data.imgPath + `);"
          />
          <div class="screen" />
          <div class="wrap">
            <div class="entry">
              <h2>`+ data.title +`</h2>
              <h4>`+ data.tagline +`<//h4>

              <span
                class="play-button button"
                data-vimeo-id="`+ data.vimeo +`"
                data-vimeo-iframe='&lt;iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/`+ data.vimeo +`?dnt=1&amp;app_id=122963" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" title="Hennessy X.O - The Seven World" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;'
              >
                Play
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>;
        `;

        $(".slideshow").append(slide);
      });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a count variable before foreach and increment it with every foreach. Then replace the 1 with count.

```
docRef
    .orderBy("order")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      totalRecords = querySnapshot.size;
      console.log(totalRecords);
      let count = 0;
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        // console.log(data.title);
        count++;
        const slide =
          `
        <div id="slide-`+ count +`" class="slide fullbleed prt"><div
            class="bg-image"
            style="background-image: url(`+ data.imgPath + `);"
          />
          <div class="screen" />
          <div class="wrap">
            <div class="entry">
              <h2>`+ data.title +`</h2>
              <h4>`+ data.tagline +`<//h4>

              <span
                class="play-button button"
                data-vimeo-id="`+ data.vimeo +`"
                data-vimeo-iframe='&lt;iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/`+ data.vimeo +`?dnt=1&amp;app_id=122963" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" title="Hennessy X.O - The Seven World" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;'
              >
                Play
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>;
        `;

        $(".slideshow").append(slide);
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: i tried this before. site dont show any data after using the count in slide

Comment: What is the div id when you inspect the page? or is there any console error in the console?

Comment: yes its working fine, there was some extra `}` which causing issue. Can you help me out, how can I fix the rest of the data.

Comment: What is the issue I dont quite understand it well

Comment: the database have 3 items and each have images, title, tagline, its fetching perfectly, but once I call on frontend, the title of 1st item show on 3rd tile

Comment: are you using database query? if yes then you can use order by something or even something like ORDER BY CASE WHEN titleName = 'something' THEN 1
              WHEN titleName = 'something2 ' THEN 2
              ELSE titleName END ASC